# palindrome check comparing 2 strings Java

Tags: java

Hello I use 2 different ways to check for a word if its a palindrome or not.. 1 way is hardcoded ( this works as expected ) and the other one I use Stringbuilder for but I always get true and never false as output. I  don't understand why its not working when not hardcoded ... here is the code I used for the test. ( the commented variabels work )

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {

      StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("did");

      StringBuilder b = a.reverse();


     // String a = "did";
     // String b = "dad";

      if(b.equals(a)) {
          System.out.println("true");
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("false");
      }

      System.out.println(b);
      }
```

Comment: Try it with a string that is not a palindrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because, [`StringBuilder#reverse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) does in place reversing. So, `a.reverse()` also changes the value of `a`.

You can create a copy of your `StringBuilder` rather.

```
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("did");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a);

    if (b.toString().equals(a.reverse().toString())) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

You need to use `toString()` to compare the contents. using `equals` on StringBuilder instances will compares `references`.